# Make Raspberry Pi Zero run non - stop by setting one system

Tags: python, debian, sensors, motion, raspberry-pi-zero

i develop a Home Detection System for office security used based on youtube video.
i also used crontab to let the coding run after reboot. The system work perfectly for the entire office hour.

**however**, every morning i discover that the device in sleep mode and did not detect any movement system or give a notification through telegram. company wifi is always available 24h. any help or suggestion will be helpful. tq in advance

crontab, sudo wi wlan0 set off

Comment: did you use Google to find method to disable `sleep mode` ? I found this: [Disable Wifi sleep mode on Pi3 and Pi ZERO W](https://community.openhab.org/t/disable-wifi-sleep-mode-on-pi3-and-pi-zero-w/29917)

Comment: dear @furas my supervisor and i have tried your method and left the raspberry overnight and the result is still the same. but thank you for your suggestion. i appreciate it